# Text string must be rendered within a <Text> component in ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Text string must be rendered within a  component in ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js
in React native I am getting this error how to solve

Comment: Can you post the component code that is creating the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check your code for characters/special characters outside the JSX tags.

Comment: This is probably it. Somewhere maybe there was a space and your linter changed it to `{" "}` - which is then a text string outside of a `<Text />`